# Split a large table into smaller tables based on the column with a json field value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table INPUT_T that look like this

| Time | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-17 09:45:35.517 | {"metadata": {"product": {"type": "commercial"}} } |
| 2023-10-17 09:45:35.517 | {"metadata": {"product": {"type": "ngo"}} } |

I like to use a SQL stored procedure to store the data from this table into another two tables `COMMERCIAL_T` and `NGO_T` based on the `metadata.product.type` field in the json column. The reason for the stored procedure is because I will trigger the procedure from a task.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: I tried a python snowpark solution where I load the table into dataframe and then generate two dataframes based on the filter. This works when the table is small and it also seems overlly complicated. I thought someone else might know an efficient way to do this using snowflake sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirement you posted I don't think you need a Stored Proc for this

```
INSERT INTO COMMERCIAL_T 
SELECT * FROM INPUT_T
WHERE JSON:metadata:product:type = 'commercial'
;
INSERT INTO NGO_T
SELECT * FROM INPUT_T
WHERE JSON:metadata:product:type = 'ngo'
;
```

Update:

If you like to insert into 2 tables with 1 read you can use [Conditional Multi-table Inserts](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table#conditional-multi-table-inserts)

```
INSERT FIRST
  WHEN JSON:metadata:product:type = 'commercial' THEN
    INTO COMMERCIAL_T 
  WHEN JSON:metadata:product:type = 'ngo' THEN
    INTO NGO_T
SELECT * FROM INPUT_T
;
```

P.S. You can use single SQL statements with tasks too.

Example:

```
CREATE TASK mytask_minute
  WAREHOUSE = mywh
  SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
AS
INSERT INTO mytable(ts) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestions. Is there anything more efficient than the double scan? sorry for the noob Q. it seems the table was scanned twice.

Comment: I added the reason for the store procedure, i am trying to trigger this from a task definition.

Comment: updated the answer, please check it out and let me know if this version meets your requirements